# Groovy Source Install "rosmake -a" Build Error

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, ros-groovy, rosmake, laser-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I've been trying to install ROS Groovy from source (following the online instruction from the wiki) on my 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 VM and have been making some progress.  But, I'm running into build problems when I execute the last step of the instructions, *2.2.3 Build the ROS Stack* with the following commands:

```
$ source ~/ros_ws/setup.bash
$ rosmake -a
```

The starts of fine, but then errors out with the following error:

```
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesostmap_2d: 5.3 sec ] [ voxel_grid: 5.3 sec ] [ bfl: 5.3 sec ] [ smach_msgs: 5.3 sec ] [ filters: 5.2 sec ] [ map_server: 5.2... [ 8 Active 53/84 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package costmap_2d
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/rospack deps-manifests costmap_2d
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'costmap_2d' depends on non-existent package 'laser_geometry' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'costmap_2d'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package costmap_2d written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/donny3000/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130119-153040/costmap_2d/build_output.log             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< costmap_2d [FAIL] [ 5.32 seconds ]                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package costmap_2d. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package bfl written to:7 sec ] [ smach_msgs: 11.7 sec ] [ filters: 11.7 sec ] [ map_server: 11.6 sec ] [ fake_local... [ 7 Active 53/84 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/donny3000/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130119-153040/bfl/build_output.log                           
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< bfl [PASS] [ 11.69 seconds ] [ 2 warnings  ]                                                                                                              
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< smach_msgs [PASS] [ 12.18 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl [PASS] [ 11.60 seconds ]                                                                                                                
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< map_server [PASS] [ 18.90 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< voxel_grid [PASS] [ 18.95 seconds ]                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< filters [PASS] [ 19.06 seconds ]                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< fake_localization [PASS] [ 19.20 seconds ]                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Built 61 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] /home/donny3000/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130119-153040
```

I've been trying to debug this, but since I'm new to ROS I haven't been able to get very far.

Has anyone else encountered this problem or a similar problem that would be able to point me in the right direction?  Maybe it's something that I'm overlooking?  Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52799/groovy-source-install-%22rosmake--a%22-build-error/) by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution that I found at this time to get the *rosmake -a* step (the last step) to work is to delete the laser_pipeline folder (i'm working with the mobile variant) in the *rosbuild* workspace and clone the laser_pipeline stack from https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_pipeline.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_pipeline.git
```

Then checkout the latest branch (at the time of this post laser_pipeline-1.5.3)

```
$ cd laser_pipeline
$ git checkout laser_pipeline-1.5.3
```

Then re-run the *rosmake -a* command.  This is what worked for me to get my workspace built.

---

Originally posted by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) with karma: 55 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1